# CORS en Symfony 3 y Angular js

Tags: angularjs, symfony, cors

Hice una Api con symfony, en la cual defino todas las cabeceras necesarias.
Desde Angular es desde donde consumo la api de symfony, la conexion con mi Api desde angular es normal en todas las peticiones, en ningun momento me da error por los CORS. 
El problema radica en que tengo una parte del sistema que genera una cantidad grande facturas, obviamente hace ciertos porcesos pesados en mi Api y retorna una respuesta. Al generar las facturas en el sistema como son más o menos 2000 usuarios, que por ende deberia generar 2000 facturas, al minuto y medio de ejecutar la funcion de generar las facturas me genera el error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://dominio.com/SistemaV2/web/recaudo/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Lo que en realidad no sé porque pasa, porque mi API esta con todas las cabeceras requeridas y en otras peticiones menos pesadas funciona correctamente desde Angular, y también hice la prueba localmente y funciona corractamente generando las casi 2000 facturas, pero haciendo esa misma prueba ya en el servidor no me permite generar todas las facturas, solo genera cierta cantidad y al minuto y medio me tira ese error.

Ojala puedan ayudarme y decirme porque en mi servidor no deja generar peticiones por un tiempo màs prolongado, porque generalmente todas esas facturas se generan en 4 min, pero mi servidor corta la ejecucion y me vota el error de los CORS, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a brindar un breve ejemplo, con lenguajes diferentes pero que cumplen con ciertas características fundamentales para un problema de CORS:

Si tu error persiste desde el retorno de tu servidor te arroja lo siguiente a lo que haces mención:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://dominio.com/SistemaV2/web/recaudo/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**Explicacion**

los datos que vienen vía AJAX tienen que pertenecer al mismo dominio. En el caso de que esto no sea así la aplicación no podrá cargar los datos por limitaciones de seguridad. Los problemas comienzan cuando nosotros tenemos aplicaciones que necesitan acceder a esos datos pero no se encuentran bajo el mismo dominio. Un ejemplo muy habitual es una aplicación Movil empaquetada con PhoneGAP o en Ionic con Angular. Por lo que en el momento en que subas tu app a un servidor esta responderá de forma correcta, es solo una limitación cuando se está trabajando de forma local (esto a manera de ejemplo en un ambiente parecido al mencionado)

**Solución**

Puedes descargar un complemento para el navegador sea Chrome(es más fácil) u otro de tu preferencia. Buscalo por ese nombre CORS y te ayudará, sólo tienes que ligar la dirección web a la que realizas tu petición con ajax. Y de esta manera permites la conexión entre ambas partes.

[image: CORS]

Otra posibilidad es que el documento o fichero al cual apuntas está codificado para evitar problemas de seguridad, y de esta manera no poder ser usada desde una aplicación externa (Un dominio X a un dominio Y).

Entonces, lo que harías sería usar este tipo de encabezados para que pueda recibir la peticion de forma correcta (Si en tu caso tienes acceso a tal fichero y claro, que sea el backend en PHP a manera de ejemplo):

```
<?php 
  //Permisos CORS

  //* es un comodin para desplegar la información a cualquier servidor que realice la peticion.
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 

  //Debemos dar permisos de acuerdo a la llamada o metodo que necesites GET,POST,UPDATE.
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

  //Para formatos JSON se debe asignar el encabezado correspondiente.
  header("Content-Type: application/json");

 ?>
```

Comment: El frontend de Angular y el Backend de symfony se encuentran alojados en el mismo ser vidor, los encabezados para que pueda recibir la peticion en el backend ya estan definidos, pero igual a la hora de generar las 2000 facturas me vota el error que te menciono de los CORS, solo me genera 700 facturas y al instante me vota el error de CROS, es como si el servidor solo dejara hacer una peticion cierta cantidad de tiempo y corta la ejecucion y por ende el backend ya no regresa los encabezados